# reading text from file, trying to tabulate some lines

Tags: jquery, file

I have a text file. Some of the data needs to be tabulated, but some doesn't. If I'm reading the text file line by line, how do I set up my html table and tabulate the data if I'm going line by line? I realize this is probably a stupid question, but I'm a little stuck.

text file (.txt):

```
 Chief Justice 
      Vote for  3
       John Doe   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .    89,000   33.00
       Jane Doe   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .    64,000   24.35
       Jim Doe    .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .    24,000    9.09
       Sally Roe  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .     8,000    3.23       

      Next Office
      Vote for  1
       Jane Jones       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .    18,000   19.13
       Bob Jones        .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .    77,000   80.58

etc....
```

html:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

jquery:

```
var file = "myfile.txt";

    $.get(file,function(data){
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {

                    if (lines[i].indexOf(".  .") < 0) {
                        $('#mydiv').append(lines[i] + "<br/>");
                    } else {
                        //??
                        //need to feed these lines into an array 
                        //and parse them
                    }

            }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pushing the lines into an array:

```
$.get(file,function(data){
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
    var myArray= [];
                if (lines[i].indexOf(".  .") < 0) {
                    $('#mydiv').append(lines[i] + "<br/>");
                         if (myArray.length > 0) {
                                //there is something in the array
                                $('#mydiv').append("<table>");
                                for (var j = 0; j<myArray.length; j++) {
                                    //parse, etc., here
                                }
                                $('#mydiv').append("</table>");
                                myArray= [];
                            }
                    } else {
                       myArray.push(lines[i]);
                    }

            }

});
```